# Protected method call from other package

Tags: java, protected, modifier

I thought I understand `protected` modifier, but it looks like I don't. 
The example is simple:

```
package com;
public class Main {

     protected void method1() {
         // some code
     }
}
```

and:

```
package net;

import com.Main;

public class Out extends Main {

    public Out(){
         Main m = new Main();
         m.method1();
    }
}
```

Why can't I call `method1` from a class that extends `Main`? Compiler error suggest to change modifier to `public`.

I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.furniture;

public class Seat {

    public boolean canAccommodate(int numberOfPeople) {
        return numberOfPeople <= getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();
    }

    protected int getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate() {
        return 4;
    }

}


package com.example.furniture;

public class Chair extends Seat {

    public boolean willBreakIfNumberOfPeopleSittingExceeds(int numberOfPeople) {
        return numberOfPeople > getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();
    }

}
```

The above would work even though `getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate()` isn't defined explicitly in `Chair`, `Chair` will use the implementation from `Seat`. The `protected` modifier allows subclasses to call (or override) the method, and also allows classes from the same package to call the method:

```
package com.example.furniture;

public class Bed {

    public boolean canFitMorePeopleThanThis(Seat seat) {
        return peopleICanFit() > seat.getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();
    }

    private int peopleICanFit() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

And classes extending the one with the protected method can override that method too:

```
package com.example.furniture;

public class ReallySmallChair extends Seat {

    public boolean willBreakIfNumberOfPeopleSittingExceeds(int numberOfPeople) {
        return numberOfPeople > getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate() {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

But if you try to access the protected method from an external package, it won't work:

```
package com.example.room;

public class LivingRoom {

    Seat seat = new Seat();
    Seat chair = new Chair();

    public boolean canAccommodate(int numberOfPeople) {
        int maxAccommodate = seat.getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate() +
                chair.getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();

        return numberOfPeople <= maxAccommodate;
    }

}
```

You'll get a compiler error when trying to access either the `seat.get...` or `chair.get...` methods.

If you had a subclass of Seat in a different package, then you could still access the protected methods because it fulfils one of the two conditions (a subclass, or another class in the same package), but only its own method:

```
package com.example.room;

public class RecreationalVehicle extends Seat {

    public boolean canAccommodate(int numberOfPeople) {
        return numberOfPeople <= getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();            
    }

}
```

That works, because `getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate()` is a method that *belongs* to `RecreationalVehicle` (it's a subclass). If it tried to access it from a `Seat` variable, it wouldn't allow it because `RecreationalVehicle` isn't allowed to touch another instance's protected methods as it's not in the same package:

```
package com.example.room;

public class RecreationalVehicle extends Seat {

    Seat seat = new Seat();

    public void foo() {
        seat.getMaxNumberOfPeopleThatICanAccommodate();            
    }

}
```

would cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you create a `Main` instance in `Out` (an `Out` is a `Main`, but a `Main` is not an `Out`).

It will work if you'll call directly `method1`:

```
public Out(){
    method1();
}
```

or if you have an `Out` instance:

```
public Out(){
    Main m = new Main();
    ((Out)m).method1();
}
```

or

```
public Out(){
    Out m = new Out();
    m.method1();
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html) you can find some details ( section 6.6.2 ):

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

Comment: The first code example is not a method. It is called `constructor` in Java. And it is very clear. He can just replace his constructor with one of my constructors and everything will work fine.

Comment: `method1()` in a class called `Out` is not a constructor

Comment: `public Out()` = a public constructor ; `method1()` = a method call ; I think that everything is clear. He can call `method1` directly because it is a protected method inherited from Main.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually can call a method of superclass from different package, you just cant do it explicitly:

```
package com.example.room;

import com.example.furniture.Seat;

public class RecreationalVehicle extends Seat{

RecreationalVehicle rec = new RecreationalVehicle();

public boolean canAccomodate(int numberOfPeople){

    int n = rec.getMaxNumber();

    getMaxNumber();
    return true;
    }
}
```

This class dont implement getMaxNumber(), yet a call rec.getMaxNumber() is OK.
That is the actual call to the superclass, right?

The point is: why can't we call methods of superclass from other package
on an object with the 'parent' reference type?

Comment: this shouldn't be posted as an answer because it's not an answer to your question. The quote posted at the end of @curiosu's answer explains -> the _only_ time you can access [a protected method] from outside of that package is when **it is declared by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object**. Subclasses are responsible for the implementation, so it can call methods in the superclass, even if the subclass is in another package.

Comment: In this code sample you've got above, you could even access the _private_ members of the RecreationalVehicle _field_, because you're in the RV class, and private modifier allows access within the class. The Seat class is outside of this scope - RV cannot change or modify the Seat class. It's a bit of a subtle difference :/